# Select the highest Id Where serviceId occurs more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have inherited a codebase in Web forms and are having trouble with a SQL query.

```
SELECT foretag.namn, foretag.epost, foretag.forlangEj, service_fakturering.* 
FROM foretag 
INNER JOIN service ON foretag.id = service.foretagsid 
INNER JOIN service_fakturering ON service.id = service_fakturering.service_id  
    WHERE service_fakturering.giltighets_datum <= DATEADD(D, 30, GETDATE())
    ORDER BY bestallnings_datum DESC, id DESC
```

In the table `service_fakturering` there are multiple rows with the same `service_id`

I need to select the last one, max id, to be used in the `INNER JOIN service_fakturering ON service.id = service_fakturering.service_id`

Comment: what is the primary key column of service_fakturering ?

Comment: It is service_fakturering.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function, along with [common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), it can be done like this:

```
WITH cte_service_fakturering AS 
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY service_id ORDER BY id DESC) RN
   FROM service_fakturering 
)
SELECT foretag.namn, foretag.epost, foretag.forlangEj, cte.* 
FROM foretag 
INNER JOIN service ON foretag.id = service.foretagsid 
INNER JOIN cte_service_fakturering cte ON service.id = cte.service_id  AND cte.RN = 1
    WHERE service_fakturering.giltighets_datum <= DATEADD(D, 30, GETDATE())
    ORDER BY bestallnings_datum DESC, id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The Sub select will group your service_fakturering rows and get the maxId for you. This is then used to join back into your query and filter for only those rows you are interested in.

```
SELECT foretag.namn, foretag.epost, foretag.forlangEj, service_fakturering.* 
FROM foretag 
INNER JOIN service ON foretag.id = service.foretagsid 
INNER JOIN service_fakturering ON service.id = service_fakturering.service_id
INNER JOIN (Select service_fakturering.service_id, Max(service_fakturering.id) as Id
            FROM service_fakturering 
            GROUP BY service_fakturering.service_id) x
          ON x.service_id = service_fakturering.service_id  
          AND x.Id = service_fakturering.Id
WHERE service_fakturering.giltighets_datum <= DATEADD(D, 30, GETDATE())
ORDER BY bestallnings_datum DESC, id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
You could use `ROW_NUMBER` to denote an order for the set

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY service_id ORDER BY ID DESC
            ) ROWNUM
    FROM service_fakturering
    )
SELECT foretag.namn
    , foretag.epost
    , foretag.forlangEj
    , service_fakturering.*
FROM foretag
INNER JOIN service
    ON foretag.id = service.foretagsid
INNER JOIN service_fakturering
    ON service.id = service_fakturering.service_id
        AND ROW_NUM = 1
WHERE service_fakturering.giltighets_datum <= DATEADD(D, 30, GETDATE())
ORDER BY bestallnings_datum DESC
    , id DESC
```